# Keep order while columns.AddRange() in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my code for my UserDynamicSetsControl

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { this.ColumnsA,this.ColumnB,this.ColumnsC,this.ColumnD});
```

And the second solution (I use it interchangeably)

```
var list= new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] { this.ColumnsA,this.ColumnB,this.ColumnsC,this.ColumnD};

foreach (DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn in list)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dataGridViewColumn);
            }
```

Those codes works, but add columns in wrong order , e.g. columnB,columnC,columnA,columnD.

How to make sure that those column are in good order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the DisplayIndexs on the columns that you are adding? Ensure that ColumnA has a DisplayIndex of 0, and Column B an 1 etc.

Link to the MSDN regarding DisplayIndex
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx

Not 100% sure though, Im used to working with the xceed datagrid not the micorsoft one.

Comment: You have right :(int index = 0; index < list.Length; index++)
            {
                DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = list[index];
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dataGridViewColumn);
                dataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex = index;
            }